# problems with setinterval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to create a simple javascript counter using the setinterval function

What I have is the following.  it works just fine but it resets whenever I hit refresh.  What do I do to make sure that the counter continues even if someone hits the refresh button?

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    count = 1000;
    window.onload = init;

    function init() {
        window.setInterval(incre,1000);
    }

    function incre(){
        count++;
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = count;
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: Cookies are an option.

Comment: How do you intend to handle the elapsed time during unload/reload?

Comment: State is not kept between page views. You'll have to persist it somewhere.

Comment: Options are: cookies, server-side, "HTML5 storage", the anchor part of the URL (OMG - don't, but it is possible since you can set it from within the page without triggering a reload, and it will persist).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) to store the counter every time you increment it:

```
function incre() {
    var count = sessionStorage.getItem("myCounter") || 1000; // set it to 1000 as per your initialization
    count++;
    sessionStorage.setItem("myCounter", count);
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = count;
}
```